# Is there a way to disable jit generic code sharing?

Tags: c#, generics, optimization, jit

When a generic method is called, there is one instance of specialized method for specific generic type only for generic value type argument.

In case of generic referene type argument, code is shared because datalength (pointer) is the same for all reference type.

This mechanism exist mainly to avoid "code bloat". For me, code bloat is not a problem because generic type or method is never parameterized with a lot of differents types.

I look for a way to prevent JIT to share generic code between generic reference argument.

Comment: (1) You can't. (2) I can think of no valid reason to want to do so.

Comment: I can't think of any way in which this code sharing imposes *any* form of overhead. What benefit do *you* perceive in doing this?

Comment: The same benfit you can receive by disable jit optimization... Developping advanced debugging tools using unsafe code, optimize code at runtime, etc. The direct benefit in my current project is performance (sacrifice memory usage for execution speed).

Comment: But you wouldn't get any benefit to execution speed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sharing means that every call needs to be indirectly through an interface. That has several cycles of overhead by itself, and it prevents inclining and type specific optimizations.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - I'd have thought there are very few type specific optimizations available given the other constraints on generic method implementations that are already imposed. To get the sort of benefits you're talking about, it'd be more along the lines of "can we completely redesign how generics work in C#?" which isn't the question posed.

Comment: not need to redesign how generic work, just keep real and same process independant to generic argument. I just need yo have a method instantiation by argument, it work like this only for value type, not for reference type :-(